# How to get the context object in Custom Controller Umbraco 5?

Tags: requestcontext, umbraco5

I want to access GetDictionaryItem() function in my custom Controller so i need the Context object, i am accessing data from the Custom controller by plain jquery Ajax.

i can access the GetdictionaryItem in my SurfaceController as below

```
var dictionaryHelper = new DictionaryHelper(_routableRequestContext.Application);
        string dearDictonaryItem = dictionaryHelper.GetDictionaryItemValueForLanguage("Common/Dear", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name, "Dear");
```

But i also need it in my Custom Controller,

Thanks,
Sher

Comment: What's stopping you from creating your custom controller as a surface controller?

Comment: Now thats an intriguing thought, can you post it as an answer....So everyone could benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create custom controller as a surface controller,

Thanks to @seraphym